# finding feasible solution to LP is equally hard as optimal solution

Tags: matrices, optimization, proof-explanation, linear-programming, duality-theorems

I have hard time grasping this proof which should follow from duality theorem.

Could someone elaborate on what is going on?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, If I understand it correctly...

=> If I have optimal solution to (P) then I create vector y and this combined vector $(x_1,...,x_m,y_1,...y_m)$ is feasible solution to the combined LP.

<= If I have feasible solution to combined program $w=(x_1,...,x_m,y_1,...y_m)$,
then I just take x part,and it is optimal solution of (P) because in combined LP we are too maximizing $c^Tx$ subject to Ax<=b.